# Are there more differences on the charts than the actual viewing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts, mschart

I was creating a chart with different series consisting of line, and stackedColumns. *(See Picture 1)* but when I changed the line series to a point series, the stackedColumn changed as well *(Picture 2)*.

Any idea what has happened here to alter my stackedcolumn chart?

**Picture 1**
 [image: Picture 1]

**Picture 2**
[image]

**Code:**

```
<asp:Chart ID="chrSteam" runat="server"  >
    <Series>
THIS IS THE ONE I CHANGED-
     <asp:Series Name="Skillnad" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Green" ChartType="point"'line BorderWidth="2"></asp:Series>

     <asp:Series Name="serGoodColNeg" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Green" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
     <asp:Series Name="serLowCol" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="#E5E500" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
     <asp:Series Name="serLowLowCol" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Red" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
     <asp:Series Name="serGoodColPos" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Green" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>    
     <asp:Series Name="serLowLimit" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="#808080" ChartType="StepLine" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
     <asp:Series Name="serLowLowLimit" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="#808080" ChartType="StepLine" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
   <ChartAreas>
   <asp:ChartArea Name="chrSteam" ></asp:ChartArea>


    'Lines for limits
    For i As Integer = 0 To 8 'Past 7 days
        With chrCurrent
            .Series("serLowLimit").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1 - i), (limitGoodNeg))
            .Series("serLowLowLimit").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1 - i), (limitYellowLow + limitGoodNeg))
        End With
    Next
    'COLUM
    With chrCurrent

        .Series("serLowCol").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (limitYellowLow))
        .Series("serLowLowCol").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (limitYellowLow + limitGoodNeg))
        .Series("serGoodColNeg").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (limitGoodNeg))
        .Series("serGoodColPos").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (20))

    End With
```

Comment: to me it looks like `chrCurrent` has 4 series in it not 3 thats why there could be a possibly that white gap in the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the postion series postion to last and not first.

```
 <asp:Series Name="serGoodColNeg" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Green" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
 <asp:Series Name="serLowCol" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="#E5E500" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
 <asp:Series Name="serLowLowCol" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Red" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
 <asp:Series Name="serGoodColPos" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Green" ChartType="StackedColumn" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>    
 <asp:Series Name="serLowLimit" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="#808080" ChartType="StepLine" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
 <asp:Series Name="serLowLowLimit" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="#808080" ChartType="StepLine" BorderWidth="1"></asp:Series>
</Series>
THIS IS THE ONE I CHANGED-
 <asp:Series Name="Skillnad" ChartArea="chrSteam" Color="Green" ChartType="point"'line BorderWidth="2"></asp:Series>
```

```
'Lines for limits
For i As Integer = 0 To 8 'Past 7 days
    With chrCurrent
        .Series("serLowLimit").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1 - i), (limitGoodNeg))
        .Series("serLowLowLimit").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1 - i), (limitYellowLow + limitGoodNeg))
    End With
Next
'COLUM
With chrCurrent

    .Series("serLowCol").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (limitYellowLow))
    .Series("serLowLowCol").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (limitYellowLow + limitGoodNeg))
    .Series("serGoodColNeg").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (limitGoodNeg))
    .Series("serGoodColPos").Points.AddXY(DateSerial(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day + 1), (20))

End With
```